# How to stream audio from ffserver

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp, ffserver, matroska

I trying to stream 2 files - `1.mkv` without audio (which streaming ok) and `2.mkv` with audio encoded with Vorbis codec which i can't stream. For encoding I used

```
ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -strict -2 -c:a vorbis ex.mkv
```

And it playing ok with `ffplay`

Server log:

```
Fri May 17 00:49:08 2019 Opening feed file '1.mkv' for stream 'test1-rtsp'
Fri May 17 00:49:08 2019 [matroska,webm @ 0x200746c0]Unknown entry 0x55B0
Thu Dec 14 21:35:00 1950 [h264 @ 0x2007dcc0]gray chroma
Fri May 17 00:49:08 2019 [h264 @ 0x2007dcc0]error while decoding MB 18 1, bytestream 1989
Fri May 17 00:49:08 2019 [h264 @ 0x2007dcc0]concealing 432 DC, 432 AC, 432 MV errors in I frame
Fri May 17 00:49:08 2019 Opening feed file '2.mkv' for stream 'test2-rtsp'
Fri May 17 00:49:08 2019 [matroska,webm @ 0x200746c0]Unknown entry 0x55B0
Fri May 17 00:49:08 2019 FFserver started.
Fri May 17 00:49:25 2019 [matroska,webm @ 0x20080de0]Unknown entry 0x55B0
Fri May 17 00:49:25 2019 127.0.0.1:33582 - - "PLAY test2-rtsp/streamid=0 RTP/UDP"
Fri May 17 00:49:25 2019 127.0.0.1 - - [SETUP] "rtsp://127.0.0.1:7654/test2-rtsp/ RTSP/1.0" 200 2553
```

Client log:

```
Bad packed header lengths (30,0,1250,2673)
[udp @ 00000236f6318500] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 00000236f63185c0] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 00000236f633dc40] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 00000236f634df00] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[rtsp @ 00000236f63153c0] method SETUP failed: 503 Service Unavailable
rtsp://127.0.0.1:7654/test2-rtsp: Server returned 5XX Server Error reply
```

Configure ffserver file:

```
Port 8090
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 500000
CustomLog -
NoDaemon

RTSPPort 7654
RTSPBindAddress 0.0.0.0

<Stream test1-rtsp>
    Format rtp
    File "1.mkv"
</Stream>
<Stream test2-rtsp>
    Format rtp
    Strict -2
    AudioCodec vorbis
    File "2.mkv"
</Stream>
```

Answer (score 0):

first convert

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

Then stream

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -crf 18 http://localhost:1234/feed1.ffm
```

Also there is high chance you can combine the two of them into single script by speicify input codec and output codec. But need to keep trying

Comment: How can I do it with using ffserver (what should I write in config file), not ffmpeg?